# How is folding setup in org-mode?

Tags: code-folding

I'm trying to setup folding for Abaqus/Calculix inp files.

The format is basically as follows: keywords are represented as * and it's contents are what follows. This is quite like org-mode.

So far I've tried [origami](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Folding) but the results are not satisfactory. It either folds blocks delimited by {} or indented blocks, while neither of which are really necessary here.

I already have a basic major-mode setup for syntax highlighting. I'd like to know what I need to add so that I can emulate org like folding.

Vim, however, manages this off-the-shelf.

Comment: Org-mode uses `outline-minor-mode`. The variable `outline-regexp` controls what portion of texts are folded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `outline-toggle-children` is exactly what I was looking for.